# Extract values of two columns from a dataset based on the column's value of another dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract values of two columns from a dataset based on the column's value of another dataset.

Example:

df1:

```
index      ID            Value
0          45            04      
1          32            03       
2          34            08    
3          6             05    
4          45            04
```

df2

```
index      ID            Weight    Height        
0          6             50        155   
1          32            55        164     
2          34            66        162    
3          45            54        163
4          99            55        155
```

I would like to get:

df1

```
index      ID            Value            Weight            Height  
0          45            04               54                163
1          32            03               55                164   
2          34            08               66                162   
3          6             05               50                155  
4          45            04               54                163
```

I tried:

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on="id")`

But it gives me a bigger dataset than df1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join and for avoid duplicates remove them from `df2` by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates('ID'), on="ID", how='left')
```

Comment: I think you mean `df1.drop_duplicates`

Comment: @gold_cy - No, because in original ouput is more rows like `df1`, so it means `ID` is duplicated in both `df1, df2`. So for correct ouput need remove dupes from `df2`

Comment: `df2` has no dupes prior to a merge

Comment: @gold_cy - ya, in sample data not, but what is reason for OP `But it gives me a bigger dataset than df1.` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do as you wanted and just drop an extra column:

```
(pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", suffixes=('', '_y'))
   .drop('index_y', axis=1)
   .sort_values('index')
)
```

Output:

```
index   ID  Value   Weight  Height
    0   45      4       54     163
    1   32      3       55     164
    2   34      8       66     162
    3    6      5       50     155
    4   45      4       54     163
```

Comment: first 2 columns are indexes, so OP need `pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID")`